# How do I render a list or table of my own elements with react-window?

Tags: reactjs, react-window

I have an array of thousands of objects, like

```
const people = [
    { name: "Alan", age: 36, score: 103428 },
    { name: "Belinda", age: 40, score: 1482822 },
    { name: "Carol", age: 51, score: 78492391 },
    ...
];
```

I want to display a table where each person object is a row, but there are so many of them and their `score` field updates every few seconds, and it bogs the user's machine down.

This seems the perfect opportunity to try out react-window. Only say 20 of these objects will be onscreen at any moment, so I'll just display and re-render the ones that are in the viewport right now.

But I just can't make sense of the react-window examples or documentation. Here's the example it gives for a fixed-size grid:

```
const Cell = ({ columnIndex, rowIndex, style }) => (
  <div style={style}>
    Item {rowIndex},{columnIndex}
  </div>
);

const Example = () => (
  <Grid
    columnCount={1000}
    columnWidth={100}
    height={150}
    rowCount={1000}
    rowHeight={35}
    width={300}
  >
    {Cell}
  </Grid>
);
```

There's some kind of magic happening with how a `FixedSizeGrid` renders its children but I don't know what it is, and I don't know how I could replace `Cell` with a component of my own. Where are the `style`, `columnIndex` and `rowIndex` props coming from? I'm reading the source code and can't figure that out. It's not mentioned anywhere that you can give an array/collection to one of the react-window components so how do you map an array to one? The only way I can see to do it is by indexing into my `people` array, but that feels... wrong? Wouldn't that lead to sorting becoming very expensive for example?